# "no template named 'WeakCallbackData' in namespace 'v8'" error when installing npm packages

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, v8, node-fibers

Some packages that depend on https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers fail to install with error message above. Particularly it is iron-meteor.

Homepage of the fibers states:

> meteor users please read this
>
> If you're trying to get meteor running and you ended up at this page you're probably doing something wrong. Please uninstall all versions of NodeJS and Meteor, then start over. See meteor#5124 for more information."

But it does not seem to be very helpful.

One guy recommends to downgrade node.js here https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2991

It helps indeed, but it is kind of hack, right?

Node version affected: v7.2.0

Node v6.9.2 works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WeakCallbackData was removed](https://codereview.chromium.org/1953263002) from the V8 API earlier this year. Since this change has landed in Node 7, packages that rely on v8::WeakCallbackData don't work anymore. You need to downgrade Node or wait until Meteor supports Node 7, i.e., uses a newer node-fibers version.